# Почему не ставиться php extension redis?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

пытаюсь поставить подключить контейнер редиса вот compose

```
  php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./:/www"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_PHP_CONFIG=${DOCKER_PHP_CONFIG}
      - DOCKER_XDEBUG=${DOCKER_XDEBUG}
      - DOCKER_SUPERVISOR=${DOCKER_SUPERVISOR}
      - DOCKER_CRON=${DOCKER_CRON}
    networks:
        - laravel
      php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./:/www"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_PHP_CONFIG=${DOCKER_PHP_CONFIG}
      - DOCKER_XDEBUG=${DOCKER_XDEBUG}
      - DOCKER_SUPERVISOR=${DOCKER_SUPERVISOR}
      - DOCKER_CRON=${DOCKER_CRON}
    networks:
        - laravel
```

вот так в dockerfile php-fpm

```
RUN pecl install redis-5.3.1 \
 && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

вот такой ответ получаю

```
Starting to download redis-5.3.1.tgz (264,485 bytes)
......................................................done: 264,485 bytes
29 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install redis-5.3.1  && docker-php-ext-enable redis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

что не так то ?

Comment: возможно стоит поставить `autoconf`: `Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten пробовал эффекта 0
да и ктомуже вот так чутка по выше стоит 
`RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .make-ext-deps \
   libpng-dev \
   libjpeg-turbo-dev \
   freetype-dev \
   $PHPIZE_DEPS\
   autoconf`